# Rotate point about arbitrary axis in 3D

Tags: c#, rotation

I have a point(xi, yi, zi) on a sphere (of radius 1, centered at origin) that I want to rotate by angle (omega) about a specified axis (xa, ya, za). I then want to recover which direction, relative to my original point, rotating the point by that angle is pointing.

In other words, I want to know if I'm rotating the point up, or down and left or right and how much of the rotation is left/right vs the total rotation and up/down vs the total rotation.

This needs to work as I approach the poles(z = +/-1). That is, say I'm rotating up near the north pole. My original point might be on the other side of the sphere from the new point, but I still want to return up.

Ideally, this should return an angle from 0 to 2 pi, where 0 = rotate right, pi/2 = rotate up, pi = rotate left, etc. However, I can also work with a 2d vector with relative magnitude and directions for both horizontal and vertical directions.

I expect someone to already have built a function for this. However, I can't seem to find it. I built my own... however, it doesn't work. Towards the poles, it will seemingly return the incorrect direction for at least one point when rotating about the z axis. However, I don't understand the problem well enough to predict why it is wrong, let alone what element in the code is incorrect.

Every answer I could find is for rotating around the z axis only or otherwise rotating in only two dimensions. The closest thread to my problem that I could find is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29496107/how-to-minimize-floating-point-inaccuracy-in-rotating-a-point-in-3d-space-about) however this would return the new point, rather than the direction of rotation, and I don't understand that function well enough to include it in my function.

```
public double[] Rotate(double xi, double yi, double zi, double xa, double ya, double za, double omega)
{
    //xi,yi,zi is our pt
    //xa,ya,za is our axis
    //omega is our angle of rotation
    //Prepare output
    double[] output = new double[2];
    //Rotate our point
    double turnVar = (xi * xa + yi * ya + zi * za) * (1 - Math.Cos(omega));
    double xn = turnVar + xi * Math.Cos(omega) + (-za * yi + ya * zi) * Math.Sin(omega);
    double yn = turnVar + yi * Math.Cos(omega) + (za * xi - xa * zi) * Math.Sin(omega);
    double zn = turnVar + zi * Math.Cos(omega) + (-ya * xi + xa * yi) * Math.Sin(omega);
    //Calculate difference between our new point and our old point
    double xd = xn - xi;
    double yd = yn - yi;
    double zd = zn - zi;
    //Calculate radius(at a particular z) for all points
    double ri = Math.Sqrt(xi * xi + yi * yi);
    double rn = Math.Sqrt(xn * xn + yn * yn);
    double rd = Math.Sqrt(xd * xd + yd * yd);
    //Calculate magnitude of the rotation
    double td = Math.Sqrt(rd * rd + zd * zd);
    //If our rotation is in the left direction
    if (Math.Atan2(yn, xn) < Math.Atan2(yi, xi))
    {
        //Return negative as the direction and the fraction of the rotation in the horizontal
        output[0] = -1 * rd / td;
    }
    else
    //So it should be toward the right direction
    {
        //Return positive as the direction and the fraction of the rotation in the horizontal
        output[0] = rd / td;
    }
    //But if the rotation is large, the two points are probably much closer in the opposite direction
    //ie 0.9 pi ==> 1.1 pi is right, but atan will return this as 0.9 pi ==> -0.9 pi which is left
    if (Math.Atan2(yn, xn) - Math.Atan2(yi, xi) > 0.5 * Math.PI)
    {
        //Adjust the output for this border issue
        output[0] = output[0] * -1;
    }
    //If we are near the poles
    //Using omega/2 as the range for the poles...
    if (Math.Abs(Math.Atan2(zn, rn)) > (Math.PI / 2) - 0.5 * omega || Math.Abs(Math.Atan2(zi, ri)) > (Math.PI / 2) - 0.5 * omega)
    {
        //If we are rotating over the top, the signs for x/y shouldn't swap
        if (Math.Sign(xi) == Math.Sign(xn) && Math.Sign(yi) == Math.Sign(yn))
        {
            //If we are going up
            if (Math.Atan2(zn, rn) < Math.Atan2(zi, ri))
            {
                //Return negative as the direction and the fraction of the rotation in the vertical
                output[1] = -1 * zd / td;
            }
            else
            //We should be goind down
            {
                //Return positive as the direction and the fraction of the rotation in the vertical
                output[1] = zd / td;
            }
        }
        else
        //So we are rotating over the top of the poles
        {
            //Are we on the top pole?
            if (Math.Atan2(zn, rn) < 0)
            {
                //Return negative as the direction and the fraction of the rotation in the vertical
                output[1] = -1 * zd / td;
            }
            else
            //So we are on the bottom pole?
            {
                //Return positive as the direction and the fraction of the rotation in the vertical
                output[1] = zd / td;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //If we are going up
        if (Math.Atan2(zn, rn) < Math.Atan2(zi, ri))
        {
            //Return negative as the direction and the fraction of the rotation in the vertical
            output[1] = -1 * zd / td;
        }
        else
        //We should be goind down
        {
            //Return positive as the direction and the fraction of the rotation in the vertical
            output[1] = zd / td;
        }
    }
    //Return output
    return output;
}
```

Comment: Complicated array manipulations are better left for Matlab.  You can always write a matlab dll which can be called from c#.

Comment: Matlab is proprietary and inefficient for large arrays. Besides that, even if I were to use Matlab that doesn't help. I still don't know how to output the direction of a rotation of a point about an arbitrary axis relative to my point.


Since I just want the direction of a small rotation, linearizing everything should actually simplify the boundaries. However, this presents the new problem of determining the sign.

Comment: Who ever told you that Matlab is inefficient?  In some cases there are memory leaks, but it work very well on DSP applications.  Speed is very good, but it does use lots of memory.